# xubuntu: no indicator when VPN is activated

Tags: xubuntu, vpn

In ubuntu, when a VPN connection is made, the network icon in the status bar will have a lock added to it. But in Xubuntu this is not the case. This is a bit annoying since I have to go up and click the icon and navigate to the vpn menu to see which network I'm connected too.

Is this a bug or a missing feature?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Xubuntu 14.04.  It looks like we're running into this bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-icon-theme/+bug/772709).